# Matplotlib cutting x-axis labels/ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

When passing data into the following method:

```py
def plot(x,y,dateList):
    """Plot x, y on cartesian plane
    """  
    host = host_subplot(111)

    par = host.twiny()

    #Set number of ticks
    numTicks = np.arange(0, len(x), step=10)

    #Get corresponding timestamps in form of list
    j=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i%10 == 0:
            newList.append(dateList[i])
            j+=1

    # Set x-axis labels ("ticks")
    plt.xticks(ticks=numTicks, labels=newList, rotation=45)

    # Set axis labels
    host.set_xlabel("Time")
    host.set_ylabel("Black Carbon Concentration (μg/m3)")

    p1, = host.plot(x, label="Indoor")
    p2, = par.plot(y, label="Outdoor")

    plt.grid(True)

    plt.show()
```

The resultant plot is displayed:
[image: Plot]

Notice the x-axis labels are halfway cut off. How can I adjust it so it does displays the whole value aside from reducing the font?

Comment: try to add `plt.savefig(bbox_inches="tight")`